# wordpress limit user view of users with lower role permisions

Tags: php, wordpress, roles, wordpress-rest-api

I have not been able to find a plugin in or any info on this.  Think this should be pretty simple.  I want user to be able to see the user list but only have it show users of the same or lesser role.

for example 
The Administrator can see all user
The Editor the editor can see authors and contributors
The Author author can only see contributors 
The Contributor and only see subscribers

I have added some custom roles so my actual implementation would be the below on top of the stock WP roles

The Administrator all users
The Manager (custom role) could only see reviewers and business 
The Reviewer (custom role) could only business.
The business (custom role) does not get access to user list(this I already have working).

Comment: Ultimate member is highly recommended plugin. You can try it assign different role author, member , contributor, admin . go for it

Comment: already using it.  The problem is that it still shows all the users in the list.  The lower level users cannot edit, delete or add higher level users but they still can see them.  I need it so that they can only see lower level users in the user list

Answer (score 0):

This works, it's not exactly what I want as it just removes/hides specific users rather than user groups.  I am going to work on this and try to rewrite it to hide groups when I have some time.

```
add_action('pre_user_query','dt_pre_user_query');
function dt_pre_user_query($user_search) {
   global $current_user;
   $username = $current_user->user_login;

   if ($username != 'hiddenuser') {
      global $wpdb;
      $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',
         "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.user_login != 'hiddenuser'",$user_search->query_where);
   }
}

add_filter("views_users", "dt_list_table_views");
function dt_list_table_views($views){
   $users = count_users();
   $admins_num = $users['avail_roles']['administrator'] - 1;
   $all_num = $users['total_users'] - 1;
   $class_adm = ( strpos($views['administrator'], 'current') === false ) ? "" : "current";
   $class_all = ( strpos($views['all'], 'current') === false ) ? "" : "current";
   $views['administrator'] = '<a href="users.php?role=administrator" class="' . $class_adm . '">' . translate_user_role('Administrator') . ' <span class="count">(' . $admins_num . ')</span></a>';
   $views['all'] = '<a href="users.php" class="' . $class_all . '">' . __('All') . ' <span class="count">(' . $all_num . ')</span></a>';
   return $views;
}
```